# Displaying nested JSON as a tree dynamically as a list with toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

```js
routingController.routing1 = [{
  "id": "1",
  "flow": "Product",
  "businessUnit": "EPOS",
  "reprocessFromSourceEjbJNDI": "ReprocessFromSourceEPOSService",
  "child": [{
    "id": "1-1",
    "name": "mappingProductExtractQueue",
    "description": "description",
    "child": [{
      "id": "1-2",
      "name": "endPointEPOSQueue",
      "description": "end point description",
      "child": [{
        "id": "1-3",
        "name": "test",
        "description": "test description",
        "child": [{
          "id": "1-4",
          "name": "test",
          "description": "test description check"
        }]
      }]
    }],
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "flow": "Product",
  "businessUnit": "EPOS",
  "reprocessFromSourceEjbJNDI": "ReprocessFromSourceEPOSService",
  "child": [{
    "id": "2-1",
    "name": "mappingProductExtractQueue",
    "description": "description",
    "child": [{
      "id": "2-2",
      "name": "endPointEPOSQueue",
      "description": "end point description",
      "child": [{
        "id": "2-3",
        "name": "test",
        "description": "test description"
      }]
    }],
  }]
}]
```

Comment: Use widgets like jqxtree,jstree ..etc.

Comment: can help me with sample code , with my json @SumeshTG

Comment: @SumeshTG I think it will be better for you to Google some tree nested jQuery or JS plugins that work and tutorials. There are some AngularJS nested tree tutorials already so start there. Try your json and manipulate the array and if/else as needed - if you get stuck then post your question again. This really says to me you want us to code the solution - you need to try first buddy :) Welcome to SO

Comment: https://angular-ui-tree.github.io/angular-ui-tree/#/basic-example , you can check this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
var data=[{
  "id": "1",
  "text": "Product",
  'state' : {
           'opened' : true,
           'selected' : true
   },
  "businessUnit": "EPOS",
  "reprocessFromSourceEjbJNDI": "ReprocessFromSourceEPOSService",
  "children": [{
    "id": "1-1",
    "text": "mappingProductExtractQueue",
     'state' : {
           'opened' : true         
    },
    "description": "description",
    "children": [{
      "id": "1-2",
      "text": "endPointEPOSQueue",
      'state' : {
           'opened' : true         
      },
      "description": "end point description",
      "child": [{
        "id": "1-3",
        "text": "test",
        "description": "test description",
        "children": [{
          "id": "1-4",
          "text": "test",
          "description": "test description check"
        }]
      }]
    }],
  }]
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "text": "Product",
  'state' : {
           'opened' : true         
    },
  "businessUnit": "EPOS",
  "reprocessFromSourceEjbJNDI": "ReprocessFromSourceEPOSService",
  "children": [{
    "id": "2-1",
    "text": "mappingProductExtractQueue",
    "description": "description",
    "child": [{
      "id": "2-2",
      "name": "endPointEPOSQueue",
      "description": "end point description",
      "children": [{
        "id": "2-3",
        "text": "test",
        "description": "test description"
      }]
    }],
  }]
}];
  
  $('#using_json').jstree({ 'core' : {
    'data' : data
} });
});
```

```html
<html>
<head>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/jstree.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.2.1/themes/default/style.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
<div id="using_json"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

For integrating jstree with angular follow the steps.

```
npm install --save jquery jstree

npm install --save-dev @types/jquery @types/jstree
```

Then `updated src/app/app.component.html` to

```
<div id="foo">
  <ul>
    <li>Root node 1
      <ul>
        <li>Child node 1</li>
        <li><a href="#">Child node 2</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

and also update `src/app/app.component.ts` to

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  ngOnInit(): void {
    $('#foo').jstree();
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!